# Compile multiple raster extractions to one table

Tags: r, r-raster, r-sp

I have 3 rasters in which I have extracted data from using a polyline from a shapefile. Currently, I have the extraction as 3 separate lists. Is there A way I can do an extraction from all three rasters and compile them to one table with different columns for the data from each raster?

This is the current code I am using

```
  Harney_Transects <- readOGR(dsn = ".", layer = "Transect_HN")

  MeanTreeHeightHarneyBefore=raster('HN_TrMean_B_Clip.tif')
  ScanAngleHarneyBefore= raster('HNScanAngle_B_Clip.tif')
  MeanShrubHeightHarneyBefore= raster('HN_MeanShrub_B_Clip.tif')

  Extraction_Shrub_Harney= extract(MeanShrubHeightHarneyBefore,Harney_Transects)
  Extraction_Tree_Harney= extract(MeanTreeHeightHarneyBefore,Harney_Transects)
  Extraction_ScanAngle_Harney= extract(ScanAngleHarneyBefore,Harney_Transects)
```

Comment: please make your questions reproducible ---- so not refer to your particular files --- see the comments (and my answer) to your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56403276/turn-extraction-list-to-csv-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you can `stack()` all the rasters you want to extract data from, and `extract` from the stack.

Here's a fully reproducible example using two rasters and a `SpatialLines` object, like you have in your question. Skip to the last code chunk for a direct answer to your question.

```
library(sp)
library(raster)

# function to generate random rasters
gen_raster <- function(){
  r <- raster(nrows = 10, ncols = 10, res = 1, 
              xmn = 0, xmx = 10, ymn = 0, ymx = 10, 
              vals = rnorm(100, 5, 1))
  return(r)
}

# generate 2 random rasters
r1 <- gen_raster()
r2 <- gen_raster()

# view
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
  plot(r1, main = "raster 1"); plot(r2, main = "raster 2")
dev.off()
```

[image]

```
# generate transect (`SpatialLines` object)
m <- as.matrix(data.frame(x = 5.5, y = seq(0, 10, 1)))
l <- list(Lines(Line(m), "m"))
l <- SpatialLines(l)

# view the transect
plot(r1, main = "raster 1 with transect"); lines(l)
```

[image]

Running `extract` on the stacked rasters returns a list with a matrix in it. The last thing you'll want is to pull this out as a `data.frame`, which is a bit tricky.

```
rs <- stack(r1, r2)            # stack any amount of rasters to extract from
re <- extract(rs, l)           # extract at locations `l`
do.call(rbind.data.frame, re)  # convert to data.frame

    layer.1  layer.2
1  4.586890 5.115136
2  4.780503 5.093281
3  6.877302 3.337345
4  5.913230 3.755099
5  4.907834 4.887160
6  5.576908 5.386136
7  3.572350 5.225392
8  4.778727 5.391765
9  6.600041 4.205841
10 6.946321 5.544172
```

The names of the columns are the names of the raster layers in the stack. You can access these names with `names(rs)`, and modify them with `names(rs) <- c("new_name_1", "new_name_2")`.

Comment: So I followed your example but for some reason, it extracted everything to one list.

Comment: That's right, it should extract things to a `list`. Then you need to `do.call(rbind.data.frame, my_extracted_list)` to convert it into a `data.frame` with each column as a different layer in the stack. See the third code chunk of my example. You should copy/paste and run the reproducible example to see how it works, then apply it to your code.

Comment: The issue is even when I used the do.call function it was still one single list but it seems to have just been an R error.